# Are the cards in the Three Dragon Ante decks the same?

Tags: dnd-4e, dnd-3.5e, dungeons-and-dragons

So I want to get Three Dragon Ante, but I Im going to use it in Third ruleset, I just want to make sure the easier to find 4th Edition Deck could be used with the 3rd Ed rules.

Comment: Both editions of Three Dragon Ante are non-RPG card games and that would normally make this question off-topic. However, the embedded question of "do these work with D&D 3.5e?" is off-topic at [Board & Card Games SE](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/) too. Since it's marginally on-topic here, for the moment it isn't being migrated to BCG.se, but it might be at some point in the future if community consensus so decides. (Just a heads-up, is all — there's no fault implied in that!) Welcome to RPG.se, in any case. Let us show you around, give you the [tour]. Make yourself at home!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cards are different, but neither card game interacts* with the RPG rules at all, except at the level of money. Indeed, either can be played all on its own without an RPG involved, so either game will work with either D&D 3.5e or D&D 4e, or really, any other RPG. Played during an RPG, it's just a way to play out an in-RPG gambling event using a separate out-of-RPG game.

The two sets are *different* and have slightly different rules, but [they are compatible](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/63196/three-dragon-ante-emperors-gambit):

> This game can be played by itself, or in combination with the original Three-Dragon Ante card set. […]
> In addition to the added cards and rules, this game also contains complete rules for the original Three-Dragon Ante card game.

An overview of the gameplay (and the details of how the two games are compatible and differ) can be read in this review: [“Same Game, Different Thought Process”](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/515146/same-game-different-thought-process).

* No interaction in an “outward” direction from cards to the RPG, that is. There were [optional rules for the original game](https://web.archive.org/web/20201229102028/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20060919a) that allowed the RPG's mechanics (skills, new feats, and spells) to influence the card game, but there is no reliance upon a particular RPG’s rules built into the card games themselves. Unfortunately, those optional rules are no longer available from that page due [yet another](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45357/how-can-i-continue-to-access-wizards-of-the-coasts-dd-3-5-web-articles) WotC [website apocalypse](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58475/community-wizards-of-the-coast-forum-links-not-working).

Comment: Hey, hey, hey. The *Three Dragon Ante* Web enhancement ["Luck of the Draw"](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20060919a) would like a word about this *not interacting with the RPG rules at all* thing.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Hey, nice. I didn't know that existed. Unfortunately the file itself is a 404 error. :( On the plus side I have a copy in my old "3.5 stuff" archive, so I can update the answer! :) But that isn't something I can link to. :(