# Where can I find the various D&D 4e web articles? (If they even still exist.)

Tags: dnd-4e, online-resources, wizards-of-the-coast

Back in 2014, Wizards redesigned their website. A whole lot of links broke, but we figured out various archive URLs to still access the same content: [How can I continue to access Wizards of the Coast's D&D 3.5 Web articles?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45357/how-can-i-continue-to-access-wizards-of-the-coasts-dd-3-5-web-articles)

This method no longer seems to be working for accessing D&D 4e articles though — they might've been deleted, or migrated yet again without any redirection. [There's still a D&D 3.5e article archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210729144048/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/features) where some of the links even work, but I can't find an equivalent for D&D 4e, for example.

How can I access old D&D 4e articles, such as this one, which was once upon a time a wonderful article about its planes?

```
http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4ex/20081117a
```

The Web Archive, which I'd usualy fall back on here, [won't work for this page](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4ex/20081117a) "due to robots.txt."

Comment: did you try to E-Mail the WoTC customer service or call them? You could also tweet them: http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2305/

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the articles are no longer available and save for a miracle that someone in [Customer Support](https://web.archive.org/web/20190428134031/http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2305/) is able to unearth a copy and willing to put them somewhere, they might be lost forever.

However, there is still some [FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20170609011034/http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2295) telling about the fate of 4th Ed help: it is gone, they don't give any support for it anymore. However, the Updates, Errata and FAQ had been saved in a [ZIP](https://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/dnd/4ECollectedErrataFAQ.zip).

Answer (score -2):

http://dnd.wizards.com/articles is the only live WotC searchable archive of web articles. This archive includes no 4e at this time.

Comment: The earliest articles in there appear to be from 2011, while 4e started in 2007. I’m not 100% sure about this, though; I just did an old→new sort and looked at the top entries. There was one entry from 2006 in the big header space, but then everything thereafter was 2011 or later.