# How to provide XP for item creation?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, crafting, experience-points

I read [in an answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/20144/9552)  that you can provide the XP cost of an item that the party Wizard creates for you.
Unfortunately no details are given, and the link is dead.

How can I cover the Wizard's XP spending?

Comment: You may be interested in [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45357/8610)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That Web article is part 1 of the *Player's Handbook II* Web enhancement titled "Magic Items: Transferring XP Costs" that's now available [here](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20060526a). It discusses a variety of ways creatures can share among themselves XP costs incurred from crafting magic items.

For example, there's the 1st-level spell *transference* that any *Player's Handbook* full caster can learn; the *talisman of transference* (200 gp; 0.5 lbs.), a magic item that allows transferring XP; and the Ritual Transference feat, a new feat that allows transferring XP that a character gains automatically and for free after creating 5 *talismans of transference*.

Comment: It is not an answer. It is link to the answer.

Comment: @Mołot You're right, of course, and I hope it's better now. Honestly, I would've preferred to have just updated the link in the answer the question links to, but the question itself—therefore all of it's answers—are locked. As the link goes directly to item the asker wondered about directly, it appeared closer to a product identification question, and for such questions a short summary is usually sufficient. My bad for not doing a more detailed summary.